# Mark Kotlin File as Class in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

I have a running program, but one of my kotlin files is not recognized as a class.

[image: See the third file]

The project is a maven project, the hint to set the source folder did not work (which is no wonder, because all the other files in the same folder are recognized). So, how to fix that?

Comment: does the file actually contain a class?

Comment: Looking at the icon, It's recognized as a Kotlin file, which means that it probably contains more than just a class.

Comment: This is not a bug and there is nothing you need to fix. See duplicate issue for an explanation of how the icons are selected.